# Boolean Modifier Problem

Tags: modifiers

[image]
Blender 2.81: I am trying to use the boolean modifier to cut out a chunk of this square. The first time i did it it worked, and then when i tried to cut another chunk out of it, didn't work. However when i tried using another shape it somehow worked. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing exactly what you were trying to do, it is hard to know how to advise you. But some general advice about using Booleans, pre version 2.91:

- Both shapes should be closed volumes, with all normals pointing outwards
- The shapes should not have self-intersections
- The shapes should not intersect each other in such a way that edges, faces, or vertices of one shape exactly overlap edges, faces, or vertices of the other.

If any of these things is not true, Boolean *might* work but it is not guaranteed. This is probably why sometimes you tried, it worked,and other times it did not.

Blender 2.91 (to be released in late November) has a new Boolean solver that does not have problems with the second two of the above points. You can try it now in the [daily alpha release builds of 2.91](https://builder.blender.org/download/).